# PostgreSQL query to list all values of a column that are common between tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column named `endate`(its values are dates) present in five tables, `straddle0, straddle1, straddle2, straddle3 and straddle4`. My assumption regarding the data is that, one table's `endate` values are not present in any of the other mentioned tables(can be repeated in the same table though). But to confirm, I want to list all the `endate` values that might be present in multiple tables (like `01-01-2017` is present in `straddle0` and also in `straddle4` or `02-02-2017` is present in `straddle1` and also in `straddle3` and `straddle5`).

What is the PostgreSQL query for the same?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expected result?

Comment: Do you need to know which tables it is in?

Comment: Do you just want a list? Or do you want to find the exceptions of interest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `UNION ALL` and a `GROUP BY`/`HAVING`:

**Schema (PostgreSQL v13)**

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
    enddate date
);

CREATE TABLE t2 (
    enddate date
);

CREATE TABLE t3 (
    enddate date
);

INSERT INTO t1
VALUES (CURRENT_DATE), (CURRENT_DATE+1);

INSERT INTO t2
VALUES (CURRENT_DATE), (CURRENT_DATE+2), (CURRENT_DATE+2);

INSERT INTO t3
VALUES (CURRENT_DATE+2), (CURRENT_DATE+3);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
WITH all_dates AS (
    SELECT 't1' AS table_name, enddate
    FROM t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 't2' AS table_name, enddate
    FROM t2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 't3' AS table_name, enddate
    FROM t3
)
SELECT enddate, ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT table_name) AS appears_in
FROM all_dates
GROUP BY 1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT table_name) > 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

| enddate | appears_in |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-05-07T00:00:00.000Z | t1,t2 |
| 2022-05-09T00:00:00.000Z | t2,t3 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bMTX1qmYsQxFkU88RxQv7u/1)

Comment: Excellent idea: can easily be extended for extra tables. +1

Comment: I actually wanted only the dates and you gave me the tables as well in which they appear. Thank you for the answer and the bonus column as well.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what format you want the result in. I made two scripts - a simple one and a more detailed one. Perhaps this is what you need

[Here is dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=df3e58f62bf0a4547783ee36c41a65e6)

Comment: I only wanted the list of dates that were repeated. But your detailed analysis script(yep/nope one) gave me something I saved for future analysis. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
with data(dt, t) as (
    select distinct endate, 0 from straddle0 union all
    select distinct endate, 1 from straddle1 union all
    select distinct endate, 2 from straddle2 union all
    select distinct endate, 3 from straddle3 union all
    select distinct endate, 4 from straddle4
)
select dt, min(t) as t from data group by dt having count(*) = 1;
```